# how does the request calls work in NodeJs/ExpressJs?

Tags: node.js, express

As I'm learning a bit more and more about NodeJs (I'm from C# world) I've made a very simple test so I could learn about expressJs request handling flow as:

```
const express = require('express');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const app = express();

const doSomething = (res, start, id) => { 
    const time = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(`request ${id} processed and took ${time}ms`);
    res.status(200).send({ id, took: `${time}ms` });
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    const id = uuid.v4();
    const start = Date.now();
    console.log(`request [1] accepted for ${id}`);
    setTimeout(() => doSomething(res, start, id), 10000);
});

app.get('/2', (req, res) => { 
    const id = uuid.v4();
    const start = Date.now();
    console.log(`request [2] accepted for ${id}`);
    setTimeout(() => doSomething(res, start, id), 5000);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and then I opened the browser 3 times and went to `localhost:3000` and then I opened `localhost:3000/2` in a 4th tab ...

the output I got, is as this:

```
> node .\index.js
request [1] accepted for 1c928996-484d-4658-b56a-620b9c1e4060
request [2] accepted for 13d564e1-4137-4c56-9bae-b106682cbed3
request 13d564e1-4137-4c56-9bae-b106682cbed3 processed and took 5001ms
request 1c928996-484d-4658-b56a-620b9c1e4060 processed and took 10002ms
request [1] accepted for 1b64f39c-8406-4edf-a887-533cd9e8abf0
request 1b64f39c-8406-4edf-a887-533cd9e8abf0 processed and took 10002ms
request [1] accepted for 5c77656f-2105-4d65-b40e-ae0cc86e96a4
request 5c77656f-2105-4d65-b40e-ae0cc86e96a4 processed and took 10001ms
```

and what I realized was that the 2nd and 3rd browser tab they just wait and wait until the 1st and 2nd request ends (as it was the same endpoint), but the 4th tab is processed as a fresh request...

Is it possible to process each request in an async matter so the 2nd request and 3rd request take only the 10 sec waiting and not 10 sec after the previous request is processed?

I'm just wondering that in production, if an internal call to an API, for their side take longer to process (or maybe reach the 30sec timeout) I don't want for all next calls to wait for that one to end ...

is there any way to do this?

Comment: if you downvote it, please at least say why, let me learn from my mistakes...

Comment: Tested on a localhost (win10) and looks like it should look, you might have some issues with your environment possibly. And no, I am not the downvoter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hitting `localhost:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000`, and see if they end around the same time. This might be your browser limiting open connections to the same resource.

Comment: true, **same** if I use another browser ... we use Chrome for everything and I didn't even think about using others. Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the browser is doing the queuing.
I tried with one edge and chrome and both ran in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I tried curl from 4 windows and got the expected response

```
request [1] accepted for 1d37c1e9-da45-4b22-be57-de0c99d7a9b9
request [1] accepted for 2f7ee5e7-068e-4660-b606-75c3be9aa4bc
request [1] accepted for aa488dbc-da50-4578-a64c-22d47c28c301
request [2] accepted for a5181120-4709-4680-81ad-bae08c23c4f2
request a5181120-4709-4680-81ad-bae08c23c4f2 processed and took 5005ms
request 1d37c1e9-da45-4b22-be57-de0c99d7a9b9 processed and took 10004ms
request 2f7ee5e7-068e-4660-b606-75c3be9aa4bc processed and took 10002ms
request aa488dbc-da50-4578-a64c-22d47c28c301 processed and took 10003ms
```

Window 1, 2, and 3

> curl localhost:3000

window 4

> curl localhost:3000/2

So it looks like the browsers are causing the queuing.